# Webadmin or GUI for ZFS in OpenSolaris

Tags: opensolaris, zfs, graphical-user-interface

How do you enable the ZFS Webadmin or GUI in OpenSolaris? It seems possible, but not as a [directly available package](https://blogs.oracle.com/talley/entry/manage_zfs_from_your_browser). Has anyone got it working with just OpenSolaris packages, or do I have to take pieces from SolarisExpress?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my understanding, it's only available at this point in time in SXCE.  Theoretically, you could take what's needed from SXCE and bring it over to OpenSolaris, as they are basically the same core system.  I have not done this myself, so I have no idea what's actually envolved.  A good starting point would be to examine the pkg on SXCE if there is one to see what's actually installed.

Also, see here:  http://www.opensolaris.org/jive/thread.jspa?threadID=86966.  Apparently it works, but not well.  Should get you started.

Answer (score 1):

There is also NexentaStor which is a strong web GUI built onto of a modified OpenSolaris, if you have not looked at that already. Unfortunately it is modified for ZFS-only, which might be a problem for production environments as there may still be outstanding bugs that has been in existence for over 3 years running...

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question and this solution may not have existed back then, but http://www.napp-it.de/ is a great option if you need a (free) GUI to help you along.